# Storing many constants that are used in the class

Tags: java, constants

In a java application I created I make a soap call to another server to get some data. 
To build this soap request I need to add the elements with their values.
For example - To build the request I do:

```
request.addChildElement("Id");
request.addChildElement("password");
request.addChildElement("username");
request.addChildElement("message");
request.addChildElement("messageType");
```

I get a json object back and so I do something like:

```
jsonObject.get("message");
jsonObject.get("user");
jsonObject.get("role");
jsonObject.get("number");
```

As you can see I need to define strings when creating the request and getting the response. However, I don't like having to hardcode these values.

Should I just store them as constants at the top of the file? I may need to add more to the request or even need to get more from the `jsonObject` so these constants maybe cause a lot of noise the top of the class.

Comment: public static final transient Strings in other final Class, with protected empty constructor and no methods. In same package.

Comment: Looks like your data format is JSON. You may be able to use a JSON library like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and avoid using the field names as strings to a large exptent (if not completely). [GSON user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: You might consider writing an object with fields and having JAXB or Jackson map them onto the HTTP representations.